# Reordering div blocks with float

Tags: css, css-float

The page I am working with currently has a fluid container.

It can resize to screen width if the window width is above 960px, if below 960px, it will stay fixed at 960px. This is to accommodate users with larger screens.

I have three lists to display:

```
<div id="list1" style="float:left;width:500px">...</div>
<div id="list2" style="float:left;width:500px">...</div>
<div id="list3" style="float:left;width:500px">...</div>
```

But wish to order them differently when the container is larger than 1000px.

I have tried applying `clear` with no good luck. Is there a way to achieve the following without using javascript?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I can think to do this is using CSS media queries.

If it's 960 wide or less, don't float them.

if it's greater than 960, `float` list1 and list3 to the `left`, and `float` list 2 to the `right`.

i.e.

```
<div id="list1"></div>
<div id="list2"></div>
<div id="list3"></div>​
```

and the css

```
#list1 {
    background: #202020;
    height: 50px;
}
#list2 {
    background: #404040;
    height: 150px;
}
#list3 {
    background: #606060;
    height: 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 960px){
    #list1 {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;    
    }
    #list2 {
        width: 50%;
        float:right;   
    }    
    #list3 {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
}​
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/8ZVhS/ for a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think thats possible without putting a negative `margin-top` on #list3 unless you use JS to get the dynamic height of #list2